# How to use @NotNull?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot app using Jackson. I'm not using Jersey just regular Spring MVC. I have a Wrapper Request class:

```
public class WrapperRequest {
   @NotNull
   private final Object obj; // some object that corresponds with a JSON object
   @JsonCreator
   public WrapperRequest(@JsonProperty("wrapper") final Object obj) {
     this.obj = obj;
   }
   public Object getObj() {return obj}
}
```

The JSON for this would look like:

```
 {
  "wrapper":{ 
    //Object data
  } 
 }
```

The @NotNull from javax isn't working as I excepted. The way I want it to work is that if the consumer sends in a JSON that have a typo like:

```
 {
  "wrapperr":{ 
    //Object data
  } 
 }
```

Jackson will not map my wrapper class because the key in the JSON doesnt match the JsonProperty i.e ("wrapper") (so Object will be null and then I will get NPE later on if I tried to interact with Object. Am I using Jackson wrong? i.e Jackson maps things that it knows about and the rest is null or am I not using the @NotNull annotation correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson is not aware of Bean Validation annotations like `@NotNull`. For the specific case of "null", you can mark the constructor parameter as `@JsonProperty(required = true)`. More generally, you can use `@NotNull` on a property as you did and mark your MVC controller parameter with `@Valid` (which will not cause deserialization to fail but will cause Spring MVC to return a 400 if the validation fails).

Note that you may also be interested in the `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` feature, which would allow you to eliminate the need for the wrapper class in this particular case.